# rails 4 ransack gem, undefined path error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ransack

I have rails 4 app with an Events model that I want to make searchable on a variety of fields using the Ransack gem.

my controller action:

```
def index
@search = Event.ransack(params[:q])
@events = @search.result(distinct: true)
end
```

my search form in index.html.erb:

```
<%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :name_cont, class: "radius-left expand", placeholder: "Event Name" %>
<% end %>
```

However, in loading the page, I get the following error:

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method events_path' for #<#:0x007fc08b3fa838>): 1:

## Events

2: 3: <%= search_form_for @search do |f| %> 4: <%= f.text_field :name_cont, class: "radius-left expand", placeholder: "Event Name" %> 5: <% end %> 6: app/views/events/index.html.erb:3:in_app_views_events_index_html_erb___2056451196739971413_70232473324180'

when I rake routes, I get:

```
     events_show GET    /events/show(.:format)         events#show
    events_index GET    /events/index(.:format)        events#index
```

so i assume if I could get this form to point to events_index_path, it would work as expected.

what do I need to do to specify the correct path for the form?

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem.  Have you had any luck with an answer as of yet?

Comment: Tbh i am not sure what i did to get this working.

Comment: For the path stuff, see what I came up with here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30959046/ransack-undefined-method-path-rails-4-2-1  I had to explicitly state the path of the controller/route to get the search form to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Tbh i am not sure what i did to get this working. here is my controller index action now, which includes a distance/location search feature:

```
    def index
    if params[:within].present? && (params[:within].to_i > 0)
      @search = Event.near(params[:location],params[:within]).search(params[:q])
    else
      @search = Event.search(params[:q])
    end     
    @events = @search.result
  end
```